# C++ dependent template error for a construct that doesn't seem dependent

Tags: c++, templates

This is a simplified example from a real issue that came up recently. There's easy workarounds, but I'd like to understand why the error occurs in the first place. Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct Data
{
    template <typename T>
    T get_as() const
    {
        return static_cast<T>(value);
    }

    uint64_t value;
};

Data DoAdd(uint64_t input1, uint64_t input2)
{
    return Data{input1+input2};
}

template<typename T>
T DoOperation(T input1, T input2)
{
    return DoAdd(input1, input2).get_as<T>(); //Error, need template keyword

    //return Data{input1+input2}.get_as<T>(); //Alternative 1, inline the operation: OK.

    //Data value = DoAdd(input1, input2); //Alternative 2, break up into 2 steps: OK
    //value.get_as<T>();
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    uint32_t one = DoOperation(1ULL, 2ULL);
    return (one > 0);
}
```

Both GCC and clang warn that the keyword "template" is needed before get_as(), with clang's error being more useful:

```
<source>:22:34: error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'get_as' as a dependent template name
    return DoAdd(input1, input2).get_as<T>();
                                 ^
                                 template
```

However, I'm having trouble figuring out why the first line in `DoOperation` is considered a dependent template that needs the `template` keyword, but Alternative 1 and 2 are fine. If `DoAdd` was a template function, or `Data` itself was a templated struct, I think I'd see the problem, but since `DoAdd` is a normal function and not dependent on `T`, why does the expression `DoAdd(input1, input2).get_as<T>()` trigger this behavior?

Comment: I took a look at a number of related questions and answers, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24091502/753174, which says: _The general rules for adding the template qualifier are mostly similar except they typically involve templated member functions (static or otherwise) of a struct/class that is itself templated._ But that doesn't seem to apply here since `Data` is not a templated class, nor is `DoAdd` a templated function.

Comment: the return type of `DoAdd(...)` can change by overload.

Answer (score 1):

The result type of `DoAdd` does depend on `T`, it can change by *overloads*,  so you need to tell the compiler it's a template by specify `template` keyword.

---

note: the alternatives only work because you tell the compiler it's a `Data`

```cpp
template<typename T>
T DoOperation(T input1, T input2)
{
    auto value = DoAdd(input1, input2);
    value.get_as<T>(); // not work
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see now. At the time the compiler sees `DoAdd`, it doesn't know if there's also another overload of `DoAdd` taking, say `uint32_t` values and returning some other type. That also explains why I can cast input1 and intput2 to uint64_t and also avoid the error, because now only the overload of Data that takes 2 `uint64_t` values can be called.

Comment: @ScottG more like it doesn't know anything. say you may never instantiate it with `uint64_t` (or some T that overload resolution  would pick that).

Comment: @ScottG re comment update: yes it's then determined.

Comment: @ScottG correction: `uint32_t` may not work as ADL would not found it. but `T` may be other user defined type (and ADL would work).